# Usenativedriver Error when using action button - anmation issue

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I get this error when I try to add an action button:

```
Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false`
```

And I tried to add this to my code in several ways, without success. Can anyone point me in the good direction how to add this for my action-button?

This is the page where I am loading the button:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Scan from './Scan';
import Kowops from './Kowops';
import Wallet from './Wallet';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export class Main extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={styles.plainText} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}>
            This is the main page, return to registration
            </Text>
            <View style={{height:5}}></View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.FABContainer}>
            <ActionButton buttonColor="#c5e1a5">
                <ActionButton.Item 
                style={styles.actionButtonItem}
                buttonColor= '#c5e1a5'
                title="Add a thing" 
                onPress={() => console.log("notes tapped!")}
                >
                    <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
                </ActionButton.Item>
            </ActionButton>
            </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator         
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'black',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#c5e1a5',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        labelStyle: {fontSize: 14},
        style: 
        {
        backgroundColor: '#c5e1a5',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
        padding: 0,
        activeTabStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        }
        },
        tabStyle: {
            borderRightColor: 'white',
            borderRightWidth: 1,
      }

      }}>


        <Tab.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Scan" component={Scan} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Wallet" component={Wallet} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Kowops" component={Kowops} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function BottomNav() {
    return (

        <MyTabs />

    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 2,
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    },
    logoContainer: {
        height: 120,
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'center' ,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end' 
    },
    logo: {
        height: 50,
        width: 165
    },
    formContainer: {
        flex:1,
        alignItems: 'center' ,
        justifyContent: 'center' 

    },
    buttonContainer: {
    padding: 10, 
    marginBottom: 20, 
    width: 250, 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#c5e1a5'
  },
    inputTextField: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            padding: 10, 
            height: 40, 
            width: 250,
            marginBottom: 10,
            fontSize: 16,
            borderBottomWidth : 1.0,
    },
    plainText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        marginBottom: 5,
        color: '#59616e',
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    },
    actionButtonIcon: {
        fontSize: 20,
        height: 22,
        color: 'white',
      },
      FABCcontainer: {
        height: 22,
    },
    actionButtonItem: {

    },
});
```

The page for the action-button is here: https://openbase.io/js/react-native-action-button

Thanks for any help .

Tim

Comment: This is a known issue https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button/issues/339

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `yarn add -D replace-in-files-cli`
2. On package.json, add replacement scripts and postinstall script:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "replace:actionbutton": "yarn replace:actionbutton:stepone && yarn replace:actionbutton:steptwo && yarn replace:actionbutton:stepone && yarn replace:actionbutton:steptwo",
    "replace:actionbutton:stepone": "yarn replace-in-files --string='Animated.spring(this.anim, { toValue: 1 }' --replacement='Animated.spring(this.anim, { toValue: 1, useNativeDriver: false }' node_modules/react-native-action-button/ActionButton.js",
    "replace:actionbutton:steptwo": "yarn replace-in-files --string='Animated.spring(this.anim, { toValue: 0 }' --replacement='Animated.spring(this.anim, { toValue: 0, useNativeDriver: false }' node_modules/react-native-action-button/ActionButton.js",
    "postinstall": "yarn replace:actionbutton"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "replace-in-files-cli": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Tip: Do this for any fix in any package you need to fix inside node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new component to use ActionButton:

```
import ActionButton from 'react-native-circular-action-menu';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

export default class CustomActionButton extends ActionButton {
  animateButton() {
    if (this.state.active) {
      this.reset();
      return;
    }

    Animated.spring(this.state.anim, {
      toValue: 1,
      useNativeDriver: false,
      duration: 250,
    }).start();

    this.setState({ active: true });
  }

  reset() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.anim, {
      toValue: 0,
      useNativeDriver: false,
      duration: 250,
    }).start();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ active: false });
    }, 250);
  }
}
```